# What's the Best Operating System for Old Computer? Linux

Tags: 12.04

I have very old Computer

What's the Best Operating System for Old Computer?

Comment: Flagged as off-topic. Maybe a better place to post this would be at  http://unix.stackexchange.com/? AskUbuntu is for ubuntu-related questions (and this seems more like a general linux-related one).

Comment: Can you qualify what a "very old computer" is? Specs? CPU? RAM etc? Generally speaking, you can't go wrong with Lubuntu because the desktop environment is super-lightweight (it runs on a 12 year old laptop I have) but there might be a better option depending on your exact specifications

Comment: Server is always the best way to go! Then it will be fast again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lubuntu? its light version Of ubuntu > for Old computers https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Alternate_ISO

Answer (score 1):

I have a PIII, with 768RAM, and I use [WATTOS](http://www.planetwatt.com/).  Its Ubuntu based.  Try it.  R7 is based on Ubuntu 13.04, and R6 is based on Ubuntu 12.04.  I went with R6, much faster.