# which version of ubuntu is compatible for compaq presario V2555US

Tags: installation

please suggest me the UBUNTU version suitable for  compaq presario v2555US  having specifications as 
RAM:512mb,  Processor:AMD sempron 1.8 GHZ,  Hard drive:40GB

Comment: According to [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1935213) post, Ubuntu 11.10 should work if you go to the bios and allow your laptop to access the internet.

Comment: Take a look at my answer [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/309881/whats-the-best-operating-system-for-old-computer-linux/309884#309884), it might help.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend to use a desktop environment that does not need compositing (this is used for desktop effects), since compositing often consumes more than 100 MB of RAM and with your graphics chip you might not get a descent desktop experience. Therefore, Gnome 3 (Ubuntu Gnome Remix) and Unity (Ubuntu) are out of the question. In KDE (Kubuntu) one can disable compositing, but the KDE programs are also relatively heavy when it comes to RAM usage.

Long answer short: That leaves Xfce (Xubuntu) and Lxde (Lubuntu) as good candidates.

For your computer, you'll probably have to use the 32bit version.

As a personal opinion: For stability I recommend to use LTS versions of *buntu whenever possible. If you decide to use Xubuntu, I'd therefore go for the 12.04 LTS version and upgrade to 14.04 LTS once it gets its first big update (14.04.1). Sadly, there is no up to date LTS version of Lubuntu.

A second personal opinion: You might even be better off with [Debian Wheezy and Xfce](http://wiki.debian.org/Xfce#Install_a_fresh_system_with_Xfce), which is even more lightweight than Xubuntu.