# IntelPentium4 for Ubuntu

Tags: installation

Can you please tell what version of ubuntu suitable for Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 2.80 GHz , 2.79 GHz ,504 MB of RAM computer.

Comment: Take a look at my answer [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/309881/whats-the-best-operating-system-for-old-computer-linux/309884#309884), it might help.

Comment: Im running those specs on this computer with 13.04, and it runs fine. Im just doing email, and programing, nothing too intense. I did ditch unity, it was a bit too much, since Im using integrated graphics.

Comment: Opinion-based questions are not really a good fit for this site...

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend Lubuntu and Xubuntu, these are the more lightweight versions of Ubuntu.

Link to their websites, where you can download them:

- [Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net/)
- [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/)

And [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation) you can find a tutorial to install them (just like Ubuntu).